# Why is my dried out copper sulphate green when wetted with water?

Tags: color

I dried out some blue copper sulphate in an oven to see if it would turn white which it did.
I can't remember exactly but I left it overnight in the oven at around 50 C. It was white the following day.

When I put some water drop by drop on it it did not return to the original bright blue. Instead it took on a more green colour.

Why did this happen ?

The copper sulphate was bought from an chemistry chemicals supplier and the water was normal tap water which was treated for domestic use in a city. Water is drinkable.

There was definitely no ammonia in the vicinity.

Comment: Two questions : 1) What was the final temperature of your oven ? 2) Are you sure that there was no ammonia in the vicinity ? Rather small amounts of ammonia may react with copper ions to produce complex ions whose color is a different sort of blue.

Comment: I dried it at around 50 C. There was definitely no ammonia in the vicinity.

Comment: @Maurice Sorry, it turned green not purple, I don't know why I typed purple. Major typo.

Comment: The hydrate is blue , anhydrous is whitish.

Comment: @Kantura. And maybe tomorrow you will suddenly remember that the temperature was not 50°C and that it was not copper sulfate, but maybe who knows ...

Comment: @Maurice Tomorrow is here , your “maybe” didn’t happen :) Current info still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Municipal water treatment often includes [both chlorine *and* ammonia](https://www.wqa.org/Learn-About-Water/Common-Contaminants/Ammonia), creating chloramines for a stronger effect.

The color from the reaction with *ammonium hydroxide* is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TIIOj-SHkw) - I don't think this matches what you describe.

However, the production of [copper chloride](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edLpxdERQZc) (this video shows a different method) seems to be consistent with a green color.  You can search more images online to see if that matches what you saw.

There's a reason why chemistry labs like distilled water. :)